# How to use scanBarcode() from ASE in Java (without ASE)?

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, ase

I want to use this barcode scanner from ASE in normal Android application, without using or installing ASE. How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**
I do not want use ZXing's Barcode Scanner because of permission they want (read contact data etc)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ZXing's Barcode Scanner. They have very good implementation long before ASE :)

Comment: I do not want use ZXing's Barcode Scanner because of permission they want (read contact data etc)